# Diamond Operator performance

Tags: java, java-7, diamond-operator

I'm wondering if there are any known performance differences in terms of the Java 7 **diamond operator** versus the language construct for previous versions of Java.

Basically, is it faster to use this:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>()
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>()
```

or to use this:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>() 
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>()
```

Are they the same speed?

Comment: Maybe it compiles a few microseconds slower, but apart form that none.

Comment: I agree on that. I don't think that there are any differences in the resulting byte code.

Comment: How often would you have to compile code with diamond operator until it takes longer than typing out the class name would have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generated bytecode is the same. The new diamond operator is purely implemented to save programmers from having to redundantly specify the type twice.

Answer (score 4):

Negative. Due to type erasure, the diamond operator (and generics in general) have the same run-time performance as they always have (e.g. at run-time `Collections` just hold Object(s)).